# Trouble converting NSNumber to int

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Sorry about this silly question. I'm trying to learn objc and I'm unable to do a simple sum between 2 int values... In fact problem is before the sum.

I have an object that have an instance variable defined as a NSNumber and it's defined as a property as follows:

```
@interface MyObj : NSObject {
   NSNumber *count;
}
@property (readwrite, assign) NSNumber *count;
@end

@implementation MyObj
@synthetize count;
@end
```

Then I have a class that will consume MyObj:

```
- (void)total:(MyObj *)mobj {
   int count = [mobj.count intValue];

   NSLog(@"%@", mobj.count);
   NSLog(@"%@", count);

   int total = 10 + count;
   NSLog(@"%@", total);
}
```

The first NSLog prints the mobj.count nicely (let's say 5), but the second one, throws an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. And of course the program never reachs the sum.

So, what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to convert it to a int based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494002/newbie-how-sum-two-nsnumber).

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The specifier `%@` is for printing Obj-C objects, and it asks for the object’s `-description`.  The `count` in your code is an `int`.  Use `%i` for `int`s.  Check out [`NSLog()` Specifiers](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible problem:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSNumber *count;
```

you most likely want to use retain so it won't disappear out from under you (as a rule of thumb: use assign for primitive types, retain for objects)

```
@property (readwrite, retain) NSNumber *count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@", count);
```

should be:

```
NSLog(@"%i", count);
```

because it's an int, not an object.

Also look at

```
NSLog(@"%@", total);
```

because its also not an object but an int

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = [mobj.count intValue];
```

should be

```
count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[mobj.count intValue]];
```

It shows there itself, count is a NSNumber, when you are trying to set it to an int.

Comment: Not without changing the type;  that'd try to assign an NSNumber* to an int.

Answer (score 0):

in your NSLog try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [count stringValue]);
```