# Confusion due to Swift lacking implicit conversion of CGFloat

Tags: swift, types, type-conversion, cgfloat

Trying to do arithmetic in a function that returns `CGFloat, I get an error:

> Couldn't find overload for '/' that accepts supplied arguments

```
func kDCControlDegreesToRadians(x : CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{ 
     return (M_PI * (x) / 180.0) // error is here. 
}
```

Has anyone else seen this type of issue?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. While the error thrown is the same, the underlying reason here is much more nuanced than a misunderstanding of type safety and type inference.

Comment: @Mani, I suggest you try to come up with a different title for your question. As it is, it cause confusion with the alleged duplicate and might get your question closed by people who vote based on the title only.

Comment: @Cezar I've edited my title, if you feel this title make confusion, feel free to edit my title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a problem with `double` to `float` conversion.

On a 64-bit machine, `CGFloat` is defined as `double` and you will compile it without problems because `M_PI` and `x` are both doubles.

On a 32-bit machine, `CGFloat` is a `float` but `M_PI` is still a double. Unfortunately, there are no implicit casts in Swift, so you have to cast explicitly:

```
return (CGFloat(M_PI) * (x) / 180.0)
```

The type for `180.0` literal is inferred.

**In Swift 3**

`M_PI` is deprecated, use `CGFloat.pi` instead:

```
return (x * .pi / 180.0)
```

Comment: Still my mind flowing with C and Objective-C, that's problem. I got you. Working fine. Thanks @Sulthan..

Answer (score 11):

In this specific case I have a cute trick to recommend

`let π = CGFloat(M_PI)`

Unicode everywhere, and π is easy to get to with <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: +1 for a use of unicode symbol names that doesn't scare me as much as most do :D (I wonder if you could add it as an extension, as `CGFloat.π` would make it apparent what kind of value it is...)

Answer (score 1):

Its best to abstract away the complexity.  First create an extension

```
extension Double {
    /** Converts the specified value in degrees into radians. */
    func degrees() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
    }
}
```

then use it in your code such as the following example

```
let angle = 30.0.degrees()
let transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.sliderControl.transform, angle);
```

At first I was reluctant to extend Double because I don't like creating a custom tailored use of the language (from coding horrors found in C++).  However, practical experience has shown this to being a way of abstraction natural to the language.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the error:

```
func kDCControlDegreesToRadians(x : CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    return (CGFloat(M_PI) * (x) / 180.0)
}
```

The reason the error is occurring is because `x` is explicitly declared to be a `CGFloat`, while `M_PI` has the type `CDouble`, as seen in the declaration:

```
var M_PI: CDouble { get } /* pi             */
```

Because of this, you need to cast `M_PI` to type `CGFloat` so it matches the type of `x` (as I have done in the code above). This way, there is no conflict in operating on different types.

Note that, contrary to what is stated in other answers (and as @Cezar commented), **you do not need to explicitly cast `180.0` to the `CGFloat` type**, because it is a *literal*, and does not have an explicit type, so will automatically be converted to `CGFloat` without needing a manual cast.

Comment: There should be at least a compiler flag to turn this nazi type checking off. It really kills productivity

Comment: There is, it's called `-x objective-c`

Comment: @PartialyFinite that has a different kind of productivity ki]].