# Casting CGFloat to Float in Swift

Tags: casting, swift, cgfloat

I need to store a value as a `Float`, but the source data is a `CGFloat`:

```
let myFloat : Float = myRect.origin.x
```

but this results in the compiler error: 'NSNumber' is not of subtype 'Float'

So if I explicitly cast it like this:

```
let myFloat : Float = myRect.origin.x as Float
```

but this in turn results in the compiler error: 'Cannot convert the expression's type 'Float' to 'Float''

What's the correct way to do this and satisfy the compiler please?

Comment: Be aware that on 64-bit systems, casting CGFloat to Float loses precision – CGFloat is 64 bits on 64-bit systems and 32 bits on 32-bit system, Float is always 32 bits. To avoid this, you could use Double instead of Float.

Comment: possible duplicate of [swift : Confusion due to no implicit conversion of CGFloat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118134/swift-confusion-due-to-no-implicit-conversion-of-cgfloat)

Comment: if you drill down on a CGFloat in Xcode and see where it is defined you will see that it is typedef'd as a float on 32 bit architecture and a double on 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can use the `Float()` initializer:

```
let cgFloat: CGFloat = 3.14159
let someFloat = Float(cgFloat)
```

Comment: using "float" as variable name is somewhat confusing, perhaps change is to something like "swFloat"?

Comment: " 'float' is somewhat confusing". Seriously?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Yes, likely since other languages use `float` instead of `Float`, so it looks like that type/keyword instead of a variable name.

Answer (score 34):

If you are as lazy as I am, in an Extensions.swift define the following:

```
extension Int {
  var f: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension Float {
  var f: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension Double {
  var f: CGFloat { return CGFloat(self) }
}

extension CGFloat {
  var swf: Float { return Float(self) }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var someCGFloatFromFloat = 1.3.f
var someCGFloatFromInt = 2.f
var someFloatFromCGFloat = someCGFloatFromFloat.swf
```

Comment: looks like a candidate for generic struct

Comment: @Ian I don't understand your question... an example?

Answer (score 13):

Usually, the best solution is to keep the type and use `CGFloat`, even in Swift. That's because `CGFloat` has different size on 32bit and 64bit machines.

Keyword `as` can be used only for dynamic casting (for subclasses), e.g.

```
class A {
}

class B : A {
}

var a: A = B()
var b: B = a as B
```

However, `Double`, `Int`, `Float` etc are not subclasses of each other, therefore to "cast" you have to create a new instance, e.g.

```
var d: Double = 2.0
var f: Float = Float(d) //this is an initialiser call, not a cast
var i: Int = Int(d) //this is an initialiser call, not a cast
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `as` for casting a generic type into a concrete type. For example, if you had a function that accepts a generic type  that conforms to `BinaryInteger`, you can cast it to `Int` using `as?` or `as!`.